# How to write file to ubuntu linux server ? Java 11

Tags: java, linux, file, tomcat

I did deploy java web application writing with spring to ubuntu linux server via Tomcat apache.
I created folder to store all the downloads in the tomcat path inside the linux server folders :
Path :   " opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/downloads/ "

When I try to download file from external API to the ubuntu directory ( Above path )
I get Error 500 external, caused by the server not finding the path.

Method code: ( Java )

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadDataDump", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String downloadDataDump(@RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {

    String fileUrl = null;
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        fileUrl = getHotelDataDumpUrl("all", "en").getBody().getData().getURL();
        url = new URL(fileUrl);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "zstd");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    ZstdInputStream reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new ZstdInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream("//212.102.105.18/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/downloads" + fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Stack trace (from comment):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/downloads/hotelNew (Permission denied)
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:126)
   at com.hotels.river.controllers.RateHawkController.downloadDataDump(RateHawkController.java:1068)
```

Comment: You're trying to do output to a path beginning with an IP address…?

Comment: UNC paths work only on Windows, but there is really no need to transfer the file over the network, since the destination folder is local...

Comment: the destination isn't local the IP address is external machine ( ubuntu server )

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. See tomcat logfiles for more informations.

Comment: @wolfizoncontact: the destination folder is on the same machine as the Tomcat server, right? So you should use `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/...` as path.

Comment: *The destination isn't local the IP address is external machine ( ubuntu server ) –* The path implies a Samba server running on the destination. Is there one?

Comment: I tried this path: "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/..." first... then I try to add the IP because it doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68625331/edit) your question and include a stacktrace of the error.

Comment: I cannot find the stacktrace.. you have any idea where is suppose to be ? what path ?

Comment: You are sending it to stderr in your code. Usually that ends up in `$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out`, but it depends on your startup scripts. The version of Tomcat packaged by Debian 10, e.g., sends it to systemd-journal -> rsyslogd -> catalina.out.

Comment: Where is that path you talking on ? I got only these folder in the tomcat Folder : bin , conf, logs, lib, temp, webapps, work - b the way in logs folder the logs doesn't mention the exception that thrown...

Comment: This is the stack trace of the last try :java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/downloads/hotelNew (Permission denied)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
 at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:126)
 at com.hotels.river.controllers.RateHawkController.downloadDataDump(RateHawkController.java:1068)

Answer (score 2):

You have a permission problem:

- find out which user is Tomcat running as: it's the user of the `java` process,
- open a shell as Tomcat's user (let's say it is `tomcat`):

  ```
  sudo -u tomcat /bin/bash
  ```
- try creating a file:

  ```
  touch /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work/downloads/hotelNew
  ```

To create a file Tomcat needs traversal (`x`) permission to all directories and write (`w`) permission on the `downloads` folder.

Comment: so how do I open a permission to write on these directories ?

Comment: Check a [tutorial on UNIX permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm). Since you installed Tomcat manually instead of using Ubuntu's package, it is hard to guess what credentials is Tomcat using. If it is using user `tomcat`, group `tomcat` a `chown tomcat:tomcat -R /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work` and `find /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.46/work -type d chown 750 {} +` will do the trick.